# Add parameters to constructor in Ionic 4

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, constructor, ionic4

I am new to Ionic. I got a location page, and under location/location.page.ts file, there is an empty constructor generated automatically as bellow:

```
constructor() { }
```

The page runs fine with it. However, if I add any parameter to the constructor, the page cannot loaded.

```
constructor(private httpProvider: HttpProvider, public geolocation: Geolocation) { }
```

Do I have to do anything else when add parameters to constructor? I am working on an Ionic 4 project. I also added it in the appmodule.ts file. Am I still missing anything?

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: you need to bootstrap your service in a module. Most of the time they are global in app.module.ts, there you need to add it to the providers array .. check [link](https://angular.io/guide/providers) for reference ..

Comment: @EnesYalçın I added it to the app.module.ts as suggested. Still not working. Do I still miss anything? Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind to make a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) project that way it is easier for us to help you out.. and of course share with us :)

Comment: @LongDao what is the exact error message?

Comment: @TomasVancoillie got it sorted in the below answer mate. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the HttpModule in your app.modules.ts like so :

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Then add add it to your imports :

```
imports: [ 
    /// 
    HttpModule,
    ///
   ]
```

In the same file you need to declare your Gelocation provider :

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```

This time add Geolocation to the providers array.

Now in your LocationPage, your constructor needs to look like:

```
constructor(private http: Http, private location: Geolocation){
   ///
}
```

provided that you have installed the appropriate npm packages as [explained here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation)

Comment: Hey, thanks mate. Yeah that's the correct answer, works for me. I was putting the HttpModule in providers as well and struggle to understand why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Also for other services

use
`{ providedIn: 'root' }` like this in the services.

```
@Injectable(
    { providedIn: 'root' }
)
```